# C# trading indicators calculation

Tags: c#

I have a stream of stock prices and I want to design indicators calculation for them. Indicator can be imagined as an additional chart displayed next to the prices chart. More specifically, it is usually a function that takes current price and some prices berfore that and applies some function to the resulting array. The most simple example of an indicator is a simple moving average - for any given point `X` and window size `W` simple moving average is `(Y(X - W) + Y(X - W + 1) + ... + Y(X)) / W`. ([example chart](https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/l-ky83gugyn-46tqvJezaZsAte4=/1543x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/SMA-5c535f2846e0fb00012b9825.png)). One important thing is that an indicator can actually be calculated from another indicator values. Another important thing is that an indicator can actually produce multiple values as with [Bollinger Bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollinger_Bands).

So I want to design indicators in C# so that they meet the following conditions:

1. I probably want an indicator object to be stateless and manage state in a functional programming way (meaning explicit immutable state passing) because I want to be able to lazy load historical market data for a longer period and apply the same indicator object to the new data without stopping calculating new values from new real-time data.
2. I want to give users an ability to write their own indicators and the code should be "UI-friendly" (meaning that defining parameters and data sources that will appear on a UI form should be as easy as possible). I want to achieve this via defining indicator parameters and data sources as fields marked with corresponding attributes, getting them via reflection and translating into UI input elements (like number input for `int` paramter and data source drop down selector for `IDataSource<double>` data source).

Soo at this point I have something like this:

```
public interface IDataSource<TEntry>
{
    // TODO.
}

public interface IIndicatorInput
{
    TEntry GetSourceEntry<TEntry>(IDataSource<TEntry> source);
}

public interface IIndicatorState<out TEntry>
{
    TEntry GetCurrent();
}

public struct SimpleIndicatorState<T> : IIndicatorState<T>
{
    public T Current;

    public T GetCurrent() => Current;
}

public interface IIndicator<TState, TEntry> : IDataSource<TEntry>
    where TState : IIndicatorState<TEntry>
{
    TState Init();
    TState Reduce(TState state, IIndicatorInput input);
}

public abstract class Indicator<TState, TEntry> : IIndicator<TState, TEntry>, IEquatable<Indicator<TState, TEntry>>
    where TState : IIndicatorState<TEntry>
{
    public abstract TState Init();
    public abstract TState Reduce(TState state, IIndicatorInput input);

    #region Equality members

    public bool Equals(Indicator<TState, TEntry> other)
    {
        var fields = GetType().GetFields().Where(f =>
            f.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorParamAttribute)
                                                 || a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorSourceAttribute)));
        var properties = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p =>
            p.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorParamAttribute)
                                                 || a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorSourceAttribute)));

        return fields.All(field => field.GetValue(this) == field.GetValue(other)) &&
               properties.All(property => property.GetValue(this) == property.GetValue(other));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Indicator<TState, TEntry>) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var typeName = GetType().FullName;
        var hashCode = typeName != null ? typeName.GetHashCode() : 0;

        var fields = GetType().GetFields().Where(f =>
            f.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorParamAttribute)
                                                 || a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorSourceAttribute)));
        var properties = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p =>
            p.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorParamAttribute)
                                                 || a.GetType() == typeof(IndicatorSourceAttribute)));

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var fieldValue = field.GetValue(this);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ fieldValue.GetHashCode();
        }

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(this);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ propertyValue.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }

    #endregion
}

public abstract class StatelessIndicator<T> : Indicator<SimpleIndicatorState<T>, T>
{
    protected abstract T GetCurrent(IIndicatorInput input);

    public override SimpleIndicatorState<T> Init() => new SimpleIndicatorState<T>();

    public override SimpleIndicatorState<T> Reduce(SimpleIndicatorState<T> state, IIndicatorInput input) =>
        new SimpleIndicatorState<T> { Current = GetCurrent(input) };
}

public struct WindowState<TInput, TOutput> : IIndicatorState<TOutput>
{
    public TInput[] Buffer;
    public int CurrentIndex;
    public TOutput Current;

    public TOutput GetCurrent() => Current;
}

public abstract class WindowIndicator<TInput, TOutput> : Indicator<WindowState<TInput, TOutput>, TOutput>
{
    [IndicatorParam]
    public int WindowSize;

    [IndicatorSource]
    public IDataSource<TInput> Source;

    public WindowIndicator(int windowSize, IDataSource<TInput> source = null)
    {
        if (windowSize < 1)
            throw new Exception("Window size should be an integer greater than zero.");

        WindowSize = windowSize;
        Source = source;
    }

    protected abstract TOutput Aggregate(TInput[] values);
    protected abstract TOutput Default();

    public override WindowState<TInput, TOutput> Init() => new WindowState<TInput, TOutput>
    {
        Buffer = new TInput[WindowSize],
        CurrentIndex = -1,
        Current = Default(),
    };

    public override WindowState<TInput, TOutput> Reduce(WindowState<TInput, TOutput> state, IIndicatorInput input)
    {
        var buffer = new TInput[WindowSize];
        state.Buffer.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
        var currentIndex = state.CurrentIndex + 1;
        buffer[currentIndex % WindowSize] = input.GetSourceEntry<TInput>(Source);

        return new WindowState<TInput, TOutput>
        {
            Buffer = buffer,
            CurrentIndex = currentIndex,
            Current = currentIndex < WindowSize - 1 ? Default() : Aggregate(buffer),
        };
    }
}

public class Sma : WindowIndicator<double, double?>
{
    protected override double? Aggregate(double[] values) => values.Sum() / WindowSize;
    protected override double? Default() => null;

    public Sma(int windowSize, IDataSource<double> source = null) : base(windowSize, source)
    {
    }
}

public class Macd : StatelessIndicator<double>
{
    [IndicatorSource]
    public Sma SmaShort = new Sma(12);

    [IndicatorSource]
    public Sma SmaLong = new Sma(26);

    protected override double GetCurrent(IIndicatorInput input) =>
        input.GetSourceEntry(SmaShort).Value - input.GetSourceEntry(SmaLong).Value;
}
```

I think there should be like a graph of data sources and a check for cycle dependencies in this graph before calculation. A simple graph could look like this:

```
    PRICES         [root - origininal prices]
     |  |
     V  V
SMA(12) SMA(26)    [these two indicators depend on original prices]
     |  |
     V  V
     MACD          [this indicator depends on the two SMA's]
```

Oh and also I decided to allow `null` as data source param value so I don't have to actually pass something when I define default data source values (like in `public Sma SmaShort = new Sma(12);`. So I think that I could just replace `null` with root data source (i.e. original prices).

So the question is basically am I overcomplicating things? I think I could implement it simpler if not the "UI friendliness" requirement.

And also any thoughts on actually passing data sources, storing them in a graph etc?

P.S. You may notice that it should be EMA's as MACD sources, not SMA's. Ignore that, it's only for an example purposes.

Comment: I'll be honest, I did not carefully look through all your code and your requirements, but it does seem like you may be overcomplicating it. Shooting from the hip, I might just have different interfaces for the different types of indicators, e.g. make a IIndicator<InType,OutType> and then just implement an indicator in a simple class that contains whatever code it needs to do its magic. My question to you is this: would doing it that way introduce problems immediately, or are you trying to anticipate trying to solve a problem you don't yet have?